# C++ can you please help me with Composition example app?

Tags: c++, composition

Can you please help me with writing composition example app in C++ ?

I need such hierarchy : Class AppleCake inherits from base class Cake, and there is class CakePacket, which has 4 Cakes. I write some part of code, but the problem is I don't know how to add 4 Cake objects to CakePacket.  I'm a beginner in C++ so I'm sorry if there will be some stupid errors.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cake {

protected:
  int cost;
public:
  void setCostr(int a) { cost = a; }
  int getCost() { return cost; }
  Cake(int x) { cost = x;  }
  ~Cake() {  }
};


class AppleCake : public Cake {
  int diameter;
public:
  int getDiameter() { return diameter; }

  AppleCake(int x, int y): Cake(x)
    { diameter = y; }

  ~AppleCake() {  }
};


class CakePacket 
{
private:
    Cake *cArr;

    CakePacket() { }

public:
    CakePacket(Cake *x)  //there have to be 4 Cake objects in CakePacket
    : cArr(new Cake[4]) {};
};
```

And last question will be - how to create objects of CakePacket?

Later I will have to create one more composition, some class will contain 1 CakePacket. But I hope there will be no problem adding 1 CakePacket object to other class.

Thank you for all the answers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since during last hour nobody got it right... Actually @taylorc93 was the closest, but he still managed to make a mistake.

So, back to the question. CakePacket is supposed to store the Cakes, right? `Cake` is a base class, but it has no virtual methods. Using pointers is completely unnecessary in this scenario, and the only thing you have to do is to use some container. Now, which one you choose depends on desired usage of CakePacket. Let's write it in general way, then:

```
class CakePacket {
    // this can be whatever you might need; a list, set, unordered_set...
    // vector is a reasonable default
    vector<Cake> cakes;

public:
    // We'll also need a way to add them:
    void addCake(Cake cake) {
        // I'm moving the parameter to avoid copying
        // refer to "move semantics" to understand it deeper
        cakes.push_back(std::move(cake));
    }
};
```

Voila! You've asked how to create a CakePacket, and it's dead simple.

```
CakePacket cp;

cp.addCake(Cake(1));
cp.addCake(Cake(2));
cp.addCake(Cake(3));
```

Of course you can move these to the constructor of `CakePacket`, but...

```
CakePacket cp { Cake(1), Cake(2), Cake(3), Cake(4) };
```

If you want to be able to create from the array-like list, you need to provide aditional constructor taking `initializer_list<Cake>`, but I'll leave that as an exercise. (*Hint: you **won't** need a `for` loop*).

### Is CakePacket really necessary?

It's a learning question, so I am not going to be picky on it, but I'd like to point out the fact how CakePacket really does... nothing, at least in its current state. Sometimes it's easier to simply use `std` container, instead of wrapping it in a whole new type. This avoids polluting the code with superfluous classes, and you'll be amazed how much functionality standard library offers you to work with its containers.

### Caveat

If you try to store AppleCake in it, the `diameter` will get *sliced*, i.e. only the common part will be saved. In that case you'd need to either store the pointer to base class (using `boost::ptr_vector<Cake>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Cake>>`), or use something like `Boost.Variant`.

### What you certainly *don't want* to do here

... is storing raw pointers. You would have to destroy each Cake added in the CakePacket dtor, which is error-prone and simply unnecessary.

Using C-style array is also rather bad, because it constrains you with fixed size.

Comment: Your `CakePacket::addCake` needs to be `public`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this isn't too tough to work out.  Firstly, I would recommend using `std::vector` instead of any array.  If you don't know what a vector is, you can think of them as arrays that have no limits (AKA you never need to worry about if you need to expand it to add more things). You can declare a vector like this:

```
std::vector<the type of each object in the vector> someName
```

Secondly, this might be a typo, but it looks like your `AppleCake` class is inheriting from `Brake`, not `Cake`, so if this is a typo, you should fix that.

Now, to add the 4 cakes to your `CakePacket`, I would recommend that you change your `CakePacket` constructor to take in an int of how many Cakes it should hold.  Then, you can add them to the cake like this:

```
CakePacket::CakePacket(int numCakes){
  std::vector<Cake> cakes;
  for (int i = 0; i < numCakes; i++){
    Cake newCake (cakeCost); //If this is the same per cake, I would make this a const
    cakes.push_back(newCake);
  }
}
```

This will add the cakes to the vector whenever you create a new `CakePacket`.  Just don't forget to tell your constructor how many cakes to make.

Comment: You are accessing `cakes` over its size.

Comment: Okay, now it's better, but why not simply `cakes.push_back(Cake(cakeCost));` ? Also you dissalow adding cakes with explicit size using your method. Perhaps it could take a `vector` of costs of cakes, but that really depends on what OP wants.

Comment: Because I thought it would be easier for a beginner to understand this if it was shown in multiple steps... and because I didnt think of it :P

Answer (score -1):

Create object of class A,

1)In the stack,
`A a`

2)In the heap,
`A* pa = new A`

if there are parameters in the constructor such as `A(int x, int y)`, add the parameters,

`A a(1, 2)` or
`A* pa = new A(1, 2)`

The object in stack will automatically delete when it goes out of the scope it defined. But object in the heap need manually deletion.

`delete pa`.

So to create a 4 objects of cake, you need pass parameters to the object, for example,

```
    std::vector<Cake*> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        vec[i] = new Cake(i);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

to add objects to your CakePacket class, you have to modify it:

```
class CakePacket 
{
private:
    Cake *cArr[4];

public:
    CakePacket()  //there have to be 4 Cake objects in CakePacket
    {
        cArr[0] = cArr[1] = cArr[2] = cArr[3] = NULL;
    }

    ~CakePacket() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if(cArr[i]) { 
                delete cArr[i];
                cArr[i] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    bool addCake(Cake *c) {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if(!cArr[i]) {
                cArr[i] = c;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Better solution is to use a container class (like `std::vector`) instead of an array.
Now you can add cakes by calling the add method:

```
CakePacket p();
p.addCake(new AppleCake(1,2));
p.addCake(new Cake(4));
```

Comment: `-1` This will leak all cakes added that way.

Comment: So what do you suggest? Do you have some clue for better solution?

Comment: Yes, I was waiting for my internet connection to come back. Gimme 5.

Comment: Yes, it will leak, I don't wrote a dtor. I only wrote the addCake mathod to answer the question. I also don't wrote a `getCake` or `cakeCount`. It was not my intention to write a full class, only to give a litte help building a container class.

Comment: @WoJo so instead you wrote a broke piece of code that's practically useless (note how you *don't* need `cakeCount`, but **destructor is not optional**).